# SAPUI5 searchelp shows duplicate lines

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

Using SAP Gateway, I import a search help into the model of an `SEGW` project.

This creates an entity, an entity set and an implementation.

Debugging in backend and frontend shows that the search help works correctly and the JSON result contains the expected values.

But the search help UI control doesn't show all values and some or all lines shown in the control are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a search help into the model of an `SEGW` project, you are asked, which of the search help fields are key fields.

You have to mark the fields that can uniquely identify each line of the search result.

You get the described result, if you don't mark all necessary key fields.

Example: you make a search help for purchase order positions.

- if you mark only the purchase number as key field you get the described problem.
- if you mark purchase number and position number as key fields, everything works as desired.

So delete the entity and entitySet generated from the search help import in `SEGW`, start the transaction `SEGW` again(!), import the search help again and mark all necessary fields that identify a search result line.

Marking too many fields as key fields doesn't give wrong results.
But the JSON result contains more data than necessary which can make the call slower than necessary and consumes more bandwidth.